# Разбивка таблицы на страницы

Tags: jquery, php, вёрстка, javascript

Такой вопрос. Есть очень длинная таблица, которая не помещается по ширине `:-)`. Ширина ячейки определяется автоматически(содержимое примерно такого вида: `XXXX-XX-XX`). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы она отображалась порциями(постранично). Какие у вас будут предложения как это сделать, если учесть, что размер экрана никак не фиксирован. Можно использовать `JavaScript`.

Comment: Пагинация в ширину?)

Comment: Да, что-то типа того. Это возможно?

Comment: Видел реализацию на AJAX подгрузке при прокрутке...

Впринципи можно через обычные страницы с "нахлёстом"

Comment: Для моего случая лучше подойдет постраничная навигация. Тогда возникает вопрос как определять размер такой "страницы".

Comment: А нельзя увидеть эту таблицу?О_о

Comment: Если размер столбца известен - то ` len( date ) * font_width + border/padding/margin `

Comment: [Конечно][1]


  [1]: http://pics.kz/v/l1j

Comment: [timka_s][1], ширину столбца у меня определяет сам браузер (причем каждый по-разному :-)). Боюсь, что при руном определении ширины возникнет проблема со шрифтами на старых компьтерах.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/1192/timka_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C_new = C_page - 2 * C_delta;
C_start = Num_page * C_new - C_delta;
C_end = Num_page * C_new + C_delta;
if ( C_start < 0 ){
  C_start = 0;
  C_end += C_delta;
}
if ( C_end > C_max ) C_end = C_max;
```

При загрузке страницы:

1. `W_all` - Смотрим ширину окна браузера через js
2. `W` - Высчитываем место под таблицу
3. `W_col` - Ширина столбца ( желательно что-бы была одинаковой )
4. `Num_page` - Номер страницы
5. `C_page = ( W/W_col )` - Кол-во столбцов на странице
6. `C_delta` - Нахлёст столбцов на странице ( +- 5 столбцов )
7. `C_new` - Число столбцов не показываемых ранее
8. `C_start` - Номер первого столбца страницы
9. `C_end` - Номер последнего столбца страницы
10. `C_max` - Самый последний столбец

Как-то так...

Comment: timka_s, я посмотрел Ваш вариант и решил его немного доработать:

    $w=1000;  //ширина DIV'а
    $d=41;   //ширина столбца
    $n_col=floor($w/($d+2));  //сколько столбцов помещается на странице
    $num_pg=ceil($len/$n_col);   //число страниц

    $a=0; $b=$n_col-1;

    if($nomer<$num_pg-1){
 $a+=$n_col*$nomer; 
 $b+=$n_col*$nomer;
    }
    else
 {
 $a+=$n_col*$nomer; 
 $b=$len-1;
}

$m=array();

$m[0]=$a;
$m[1]=$b;
//$m[]=$

return $m;